# Running a sql multiple times with changing parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
Table1:
id | value | date
1    1        1/01/2012
1    2        2/02/2012
2    1        3/01/2012
2    4        4/01/2012
3    2        5/01/2012
4    1        5/04/2012
```

Assuming the table I have approximately 1 million records, i would like to create a PIVOT table but since I have SQL Server 2000 can't use PIVOT function.

The problem was is i need to classify these records per week and classify records per week meaning how many records were there lets before 2012-wk1 followed by wk2 ,wk3 and so on.

I have written the sql which gives output by using rank functions however i need to pass a date everytime i run the query.So i put the query inside a while loop which automatically increment every week.

Main Issue: Currently when i run the query it returns 1 result every iteration. What i want to achieve is to be able to have all these results inside a view, however, i do not want to create a table and insert records and then show it as view.

Comment: can you post your SQL Query so we can have a look at what you have tried?

Comment: @harshadbhatia : Add some sample output. You can use http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a simpler method where i created a function based on my data and did a cross apply with dates i need the data for and filtered it whether the row is valid or not which gives me better results now.

```
Select * FROM (
Select *, CASE WHEN weekNo(Tableweeks) < week(TableX) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 'Valid'
from tableX CROSS APPLY Tableweeks )
WHERE Valid = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to produce results with one count per week during the year?  If so, something like this will work:

```
select dateadd(day, 7*n.week, '2013-01-01'), count(*), sum(value)
from Table1 t1 join
     (select 0 as week union all select 1 as week union all select 2 as week
     ) n
     on datediff(day, '2013-01-01', [date]) between 7*n.week and 7*n.week + 6
group by n.week;
```